# How to set firstHour and/or minTime with shortcode in WP-FullCalendar-plugin?

Tags: wordpress, fullcalendar

FullCalendar-plugin is in question. How to set firstHour and/or minTime with shortcode? I just would like to show either hours from 7 to 17 or firsthour 7. How can I do that?

Cheers,
Sami

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by shortcode, but here is how you would go about setting the min and maxTime (if you just want to set the first hour remove min and max and insert firstHour instead):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: eventsArrayOrJSONCall,
    ...
    minTime: 7,
    maxTime: 17
});
```

Comment: And where I should put that JS in WordPress?

Comment: This is just the code to initialise the fullcalendar plugin. Generally put in a jquery document.ready (i.e. within `$(function() { /* above code goes here */});`)